# Python script won't run on Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, sql, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to get a python script to run automatically on task scheduler.

I have tried several fixes from a google search and none of them have worked.

My current action is set up as follows:

[image: Task Scheduler Configuration]

I've tried several different combinations of the action set up, including putting the script name in arguments etc.  None of this has worked.

I then added a code to the script to see how far it gets:

```
import logging, os

logpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)

logging.basicConfig(filename= logpath +'\\' +'logfile.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

logging.info("The script was here")
```

The script works up until it has to connect to a SQL server:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=dmadb;"
                      "Database=db_DMA_MIDW_INS;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your "Program" should be the path to your Python executable, "Start In" the folder your script is in and "Arguments" the name of your script

Comment: No such luck :/  Won't even run it when I do this configuration

Programe/script: C:\Users\rashlg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
Arguments:
test1.py
Start in: C:\Users\rashlg\Documents